# Copying files between two Unix hosts

Tags: unix, hosts, cp

I am running a remote ssh server from my jailbroken iPod, and once connected I have root access to its file system, however when I try to copy files from the iPod to my computer, I realize I cannot access my computer's file system in that Unix user. I am a little new to this so forgive me if I am doing something dumb, but is there some way I can get these files onto my computer?

System info:

Computer: MacBook Pro 5,5 OS X 10.8.2

Ipod: iPod touch 2,2 iOS 4.1.2

Comment: Stackoverflow is not really for these kind of questions, it is for developers. Please look through the FAQ. I think that there is a sister site for these kind of questions.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use scp. It works almost like copy, but uses ssh to copy between hosts.

From the desktop you would run something like

```
scp root@ipod:/my/file .
```

This would log in to iPod (you should replace that with the ip address or domain name you use to log in) as root user (you can replace that user with the one you use) and copy /my/file to the machine you're running the command from, in the current directory.

Comment: This is very helpful, though I am getting an error, 'scp .: not a regular file'  Is scp access always allowed when ssh access is? Also is a .jpg or .png somehow "not a regular file?" Thanks for the help.